# How to upload vmware image to ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to upload a vmware image to ec2?
I want to upload vmware vmdk images (of Linux) to ec2. Is this functionality available?
Following post says it is not available.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=292898

Comment: Only windows is supported. Otherwise you have to bundle the instance.

Comment: @datasage *nix is supported on EC2...

Comment: @Undo, its not supported in the vmdk import tool. Only windows is.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't had the need to create a custom AMI myself, but if you are already using EC2, [this service is free](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/).

Comment: The link (aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport) says - vmware workstation vmdk images can be imported into EC2.                              You can import VMware ESX and VMware Workstation VMDK images, Citrix Xen VHD images and Microsoft Hyper-V VHD images for Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2.